# heroku custom domain was working yesterday now not without any changes?

Tags: heroku, server

I made this app in heroku for like a year now
It's custom domain (Porkbun) was working properly yesterday
Now it seems that I can NOT access my app from the custom domain
[My steps](https://kb.porkbun.com/article/90-how-to-connect-herokuapp-with-porkbun) and this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zhn4.png).

[The Custom domain](http://al3wn.com) (al3wn.com’s server IP address could not be found.
) but I can access it form
[heroku app link](http://al3wn.herokuapp.com)

Note: I have not changed anything over night.

Comment: Do I understrand it  correctly, that the app is running on http://al3wn.herokuapp.com/  but usually you have a redirect from http://al3wn.com/  to that app. 

Then the problem seems to be within that pig provider. Perhaps you did not pay an inoice, they changed the configuration  or something else?    
It seems as there is no content there so either your redirect code is gone or they blocked it.

Comment: No man, i am not redirecting it. I added ALIAS and CNAME record as the documentation said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS config and /or connection config has a problem.

If you go to

http://www.al3wn.com/
note host is  **www**

You get a heroku page
[image: HEROKU page]

BUT
Your link above points to:

https://al3wn.com/  the pig page  BECAUSE it is a different host different page

[image: PIG page]

So either change your DNSor your connection string and the problem should be gone.

NOTE:  https://www.al3wn.com/  does not work as there is no valid  SSL certicicate installed.

I do not know if heroku insists in https connections but in case it does then this is another problem.
(And SSL certs can also expire - one possible problems that webpages stop to work over night.

Comment: Thank you sir ;)

Comment: If it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted. I looked into it now and it works :-) BUT YOU STILL MISS A correct SSL CERTIFICATE  so I got a warning.   Porkhost should provide you with Infos on SSL.